# How can I merge my social network contacts with regular contacts in android

Tags: contacts, google-plus

Suppose, that I have a contact Ann Fisher in my phone (it's syncing with my google account). And suppose that this Ann Fisher has google plus account Annie Fisher.

How can I tell my phone, that this is the same person?

Right now I see, that it would only 'knew' it if both names (in G+ and my phone contact) are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Open up http://www.google.com/contacts and perform a search for the person you want to merge.

[image]

Tick both contacts, click "Add to my Contacts" and the Google+ contact will have a copy of itself made from "Other Contacts" to "My Contacts", then click More -> Merge

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was actually hoping that I could do that in my phone, but that is also acceptable.

But I have a difficulty. Not all my contacts can be merged somehow...